# docker-compose error when running netcore-react app

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

When I build my app without using docker-compose :

```
docker build -t aspnetapp .
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name myapp aspnetapp
```

the docker container runs just fine. But when I try to run it, using `docker-compose up`, the image builds successfully but the website gives me errors on loading.

dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.4'

  services:
    app:
      image: aspnetapp     
      build: ./app
      ports:
        - "8080:80"
```

> ```
> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start 'npm'. To resolve this:.
>
> [1] Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
> Current PATH enviroment variable is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
> Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.
> ```

Comment: Where is your app trying to use npm if it's a dotnet application?

Comment: it's a dotnet-react app

Comment: Okay, well those react resources should be built and copied from the 'build-env"... I'm not sure if compose is really the problem here because if you had first built the container outside compose, then the entire image should be cached, and you would see no difference in behavior

Comment: but why does it not work when I use docker-compose? Everything works fine by doing docker build. I already specified in the dockerfile that it needs nodejs

Comment: You only said that the build environment has nodejs, not the runtime that apparently needs npm to do something

Comment: that's what I followed on a netcore-react tutorial. Still I don't understand why the app works perfectly when I docker build instead of using docker-compose.

Comment: Did the tutorial also use compose? Can you link to it?

Comment: no it just used a single container. As I said, it works perfectly fine the way I wrote in my post. If I try to docker-compose, that's when I get errors.

Comment: I understand all that. I'm just trying to understand based on what assumptions have you made that it should work? For example `image: aspnetapp` would use the existing image you already built, but with `build: ./app`, it might not work because it is rebuilding as different image

Comment: I tried removing either one it still doesnt work

Comment: removing 
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development   from compose fixes this. not sure why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

removing

```
environment: - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

from the compose.override file fixed all this. I'm not sure why it's the problem.

Comment: Where was that in the code you posted in the quesiton?

Answer (score 1):

Is your Dockerfile in `./` or `./app`? If it's in `./` change docker-compose.yml to `build: ./`

EDIT

I've just realised that you are specifying both `image` and `build` in your docker-compose.yml; get rid of the `image`.

Comment: ./app. I said the docker-compose builds fine. Its just when I run it that I get errors